# lie groups and coset manifolds

Tags: lie-groups

Let $G$ be a lie group, $H\subseteq K\subseteq G$ be closed subgroups , and $H$ be normal in $G$. I wonder if the coset manifold $\frac{\frac{G}{H}}{\frac{K}{H}}$ is diffeomorphic to $\frac{G}{K}$.

I would be very thankful for any help.

Comment: Yes, and the map is $gH \mapsto (gH)(K/H)$. Check that it descends to a map $G/K \to (G/H)/(K/H)$ and is 1-1. Because it is $G$-equivariant, it is a smooth map of homogeneous spaces, and a smooth fiber bundle map. Since it is 1-1, it is a diffeomorphism.

Comment: For a more general statement, see Bourbaki, Lie groups and Lie algebras, Chapter 3, §1, Proposition 13.